# Take Records from a Table and put them on a new Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to take the records from a table and put them into a new table,but I want to take them from the same column where Team Id is different and put them into a new table in 2 different columns.

First table look like this:

[image: First Table]

And Second Table:

[image: Second Table]

```
INSERT INTO `afc first round rezultate`(`team 1`)
SELECT Country FROM `afc first round` WHERE Team=1;
INSERT INTO `afc first round rezultate`(`team 2`)
SELECT Country FROM `afc first round` WHERE Team=2;
```

If I'm trying like this I will get 12 records, 6 from the first Insert and 6 from the other Insert.

That's what I want to do:

[image: Expected]

And that's what code do:

[image: Reality]

MySQL version: 8.0.11 (Default server settings)

Sorry for the noob question and thank you for your time!

Comment: Add the exact expected output from given data, to make more clear, also mention the version of your MySQL.

Comment: Are you trying to create a grid where all teams are matched against all other teams?

Comment: Please tell me you don't have table and column names with spaces?!?

Comment: I'm trying to put Teams with value `1` in `Team 1` column and Teams with value `2` in `Team 2`. And yes i have tables and columns with spaces because that's what my teacher want....

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `afc first round rezultate`(`Team 1`,`Team 2`)
SELECT (select Country FROM `afc first round` where Team=1),(select Country FROM `afc first round` where Team=2) FROM `afc first round`;
```

Edit:Actually I might I need to change.. Is there an ID on the first or second table those are similar on?

Comment: No there's no ID. And the code is not working.. :(
https://i.imgur.com/xXV4uMY.png